# Line Chart - show / hide display Y-Axis data in datatable for chart

Tags: google-visualization

For the line chart, I have 2 Y-Axes data for the DataTable and they are displayed great on the chart.   The situation I have is the 1st Y-Axis data is Historical value and the 2nd Y-Axis is the Estimated Forecast.

What I want is the Historical data chart-line to be display and hide the Forecast data chart-line until it reach a point where the display lines is flipped over (start permanently hide the historical line-chart and start showing forecast line-chart).

What property or object am I looking for that deal with show and hide data?

Thanks...

Comment: Could you share example of it? Maybe you can use `emphasis` as column role. Or different `lineWidth` for each series.

Comment: Are you looking for something that allows you to show or hide a data series?

Comment: Hmm.  LineWidth could work but it's not part of DataTable property.  Looking for something that allows me to show or hide a data series on some columns in the DataTable.

Comment: You can use a [DataView](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView) to specify which columns of data to use when drawing the chart.